# Pattern for resource reservations

Tags: design-patterns

Is there some kind of design pattern to handle resource reservations?

The problem I'm trying to solve basically could be described with a restaurant situation where an certain amount of clients can reseve some tables (resources) for certain time frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this book: [Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture, Volume 3: Patterns for Resource Management](http://posa3.org/) I think you will find something useful for you use case, although I have no idea what it exactly should be.